# Matrix factorization vs random walk with restart for recommender systems

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, matrix-decomposition, random-walk

Suppose I want to handle "friend recommendation" problem on a large social network graph. I came across random-walk-with-restart as one technique used. I was thinking of using matrix factorization as another approach.

Is there any comparative study between the two approaches?

Comment: How are you planning to integrate friendship links into matrix factorization? Also, it'd be useful to know exactly what kind of data you have available for your task.

Comment: The weight of the edges is number of interactions between the friends. I read somewhere that for the Netflix problem matrix factorization technique was used, so thought similar thing can be tried here.